# JSZip file isn't working:"'Error: The data of 'the loaded zip file' is in an unsupported format !"

Tags: javascript, html, zip, jszip

This error messages comes up:

```
"Error: The data of 'the loaded zip file' is in an unsupported format !".
```

I am using Google Chrome - latest version.

Here is a pastebin of the code: https://pastebin.com/svFjr2Jq (it is too long for stackoverflow).

You can see a template here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script>
        (jszip)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Loading...<br />
    <progress id="pBar"></progress>
    <script>
        var pBar = document.getElementById('pBar');
        var content = atob('(base64 zip)');
        var zipFile = new JSZip();
        main();
        async function loadFile(toLoad, base64) {{
            return await zipFile.file(toLoad + (base64 ? ".txt" : "")).async(base64 ? "text" : "base64");
        }}
        async function loadScript(toLoad) {{
            var content = await loadFile(toLoad, false);
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'data:text/javascript;base64,' + v;
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            await new Promise(callback => script.onload = callback);
        }}
        async function main()
        {{
            await zipFile.loadAsync(content);
            var content = await zipFile.file('load.txt').async("string");
            var files = arg0.replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
            pBar.max = files.length;
            for (var fileName of files)
            {{
                (pBar ? pBar.value++ : void 0);
                await loadScript(fileName);
            }}
        }}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should return promise when using loadAsync().
Refer to the documentation for better understanding: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html